# How to add items to xml programmatically ?

Tags: android, android-xml

I try to add item to xml contains items such as:

```
<item android:id="@+id/home3" android:title="Home" android:icon="@drawable/home"></item>
<item android:id="@+id/home3" android:title="Home2" android:icon="@drawable/home2"></item>
<item android:id="@+id/home3" android:title="Home3" android:icon="@drawable/home3"></item>
```

and I would like to add to this xml programmatically (dynamically).

Comment: Are you trying to modify resources at runtime?

Comment: Why would you want to do that

Comment: What? What are you trying to do? Do you really want to modify the **file**? Do you want to add new **items** automatically without having to type them? Or do you just want to add **menu items** (this looks like a menu to me) at runtime? Be clearer!

Comment: Yes I would like to modify resources at runtime

Comment: @mohammad rababah :- You want to add MENU ITEMS programmatically??

Comment: Not specifically add to or create resources programmatically...

Comment: You can't modify your *resources* at runtime. Besides not having access to the file, the `android:id` attributes are put as class members in the R. class at compile time.

Answer (score 1):

Depends on what XML you're talking about. Couple things:

- You can't add resources at runtime.
- You can't change `AndroidManifest` at runtime.

However, I think the important part is *why* you'd want to do that. I'm guessing you're trying to build different APKs from the same codebase. And you *can* do that! Resources, the `AndroidManifest`, and even classes can be swapped out at build time!

The answer is [product flavors](http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/user-guide#TOC-Product-flavors). To implement them you need to do two things:

1. Add new resources to flavor specific directories in your project.
2. Add those flavors to your `build.gradle` file.

### Step 1: Add Files To Swap

Here's an example application layout. There are other directories that I didn't include because they're not required to make my point:

```
├─ app
│  ├─ src
│  │  └─ main
│  │     ├─ java
│  │     │  └─ com/example/project
│  │     ├─ res
│  │     └─ AndroidManifest.xml
│  │  └─ productFlavor
│  │     ├─ java
│  │     │  └─ com/example/project
│  │     ├─ res
│  │     └─ AndroidManifest.xml
│  ├─ build.gradle
```

You don't have to include all directories in every flavor. And just as resources will "fall through" to the next best one if something doesn't exist, product flavors work the same way.

So, if I have a debug, or paid product flavor, I don't have to include different launcher icons if I want them to be the same. Only if I want them to be different.

### Step 2: Define Product Flavors

Change you `build.gradle` to look something like this. You can override almost any option available in the `defaultConfig`--and probably more. I haven't pushed the limit:

```
android {
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId 'com.example.project'
        versionCode 4
        versionName '4.0'
    }
    productFlavors {
        project1 {
            applicationId 'com.example.project1'
            versionCode 1
            versionName '1.0'
        }
        project2 {
            applicationId 'com.example.project2'
            versionCode 2
            versionName '2.0'
        }
    }
}
```